# c# sending image via socket

Tags: c#, sockets, screenshot, send

I have a problem with sending a screenshot via sockets in c#.

**Client**:

```
 private void btnCaptureScreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clientSocket = new TcpClient();
        clientSocket.Connect(txtIP.Text, 8888);

        NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

        byte[] inStream = new byte[9999999];
        serverStream.Read(inStream, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
        ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();
        Image img = (Image)ic.ConvertFrom(inStream);
        Bitmap bit = new Bitmap(img);
        bit.Save(@"C:\temp\capturas\scn" + numCapturas + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
        clientSocket.Close();
    }
```

**server**:

```
    TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(LocalIPAddress()), 8888);

    TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
    serverSocket.Start();
    NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
    Bitmap bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width,  Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    Graphics gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            Byte[] sendBytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bmpScreenshot, typeof(byte[]));
    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
    networkStream.Flush();
```

this is a part of my code. If I save the screenshot in the server to a folder, it's working correctly, but after I send it via socket to the client, the client shows only the half of the image, the other half of the image is incorrect because it's all grey.

thanks!

**EDIT**: now i tryied to improve reading logic... but now doesn't work, a ArgumentException appears when i try to save the bitmap.

**Client**:

clientSocket = new TcpClient();
        clientSocket.Connect(txtIP.Text, 8888);

```
    NetworkStream serverStream = clientSocket.GetStream();

    byte[] outStream = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("screenCapture()$");

    serverStream.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length);
    serverStream.Flush();

    byte[] bytesFrom = new byte[10025];
    serverStream.Read(bytesFrom, 0, (int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);


    String dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesFrom);
    dataFromClient = dataFromClient.Substring(0, dataFromClient.IndexOf("$"));
    Int64 lengthdata = Convert.ToInt64(dataFromClient);
    byte[] inStream = new byte[lengthdata];

    int recived = 0;
   while (recived != lengthdata)
    {
        recived += serverStream.Read(inStream, 0,(int)clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
    }

    TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
    Bitmap screenShot = (Bitmap)tc.ConvertFrom(inStream); //<--- Exception 
    screenShot.Save(@"C:\temp\capturas\scn" + numCapturas + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
    clientSocket.Close();
```

**Server:**

```
private void sendScreenCapture(NetworkStream networkStream)
{
    Bitmap bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    Graphics gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);

    gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    byte[] sendBytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(bmpScreenshot, typeof(byte[]));

    byte[] tamañoImagen = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sendBytes.Length.ToString() + "$");
    networkStream.Write(tamañoImagen, 0, tamañoImagen.Length);


    networkStream.Write(sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
    networkStream.Flush();
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Haha finally i got it, i have to control the position in the byte[]:

```
  int pos = 0;
   while (lengthdata > 0)
   {
     int recived = serverStream.Read(inStream, pos, (int)lengthdata);
     if (recived == 0) break;
     lengthdata -= recived;
     pos+=recived;
   }
```

Comment: How many bytes do you send, how many do you receive and how does the receiving end know it is done receiving?

Comment: when you say "how many bytes" is the byte[] length? in that case, the server sends 199403 and the client recive 8191 :S and I know when in theory finishes because the "Form" unfreezes.

Comment: Try using `Socket` class instead of `TcpListener` and `TcpClient`. It's better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're reading `clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize` bytes once and stop. Presumably, the image is larger, so you're missing part of it. You'll need better reading logic...

Generally speaking, sound like you're trying to home-brew a remote desktop implementation - consider using actual Remote Desktop or similar tools.